# Convert from path gives an OS error:too many open files for converting PDF files into images

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to convert PDF files into images using convert_from_path but it gives an OS_error:too many open files.It works fine for converting some PDF files.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os
#Folder Path
path = '/home/Input'
#Change the directory
os.chdir(path)
# Read pdf File
from pathlib import Path
pdf_search = Path(path).glob("*.pdf")
print(pdf_search)

#pdf_files =[str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
#print(pdf_files)
# iterate through all file
for pdf in pdf_search:
  images=convert_from_path(pdf,output_folder='/home/Output',fmt='jpg',output_file='OFD')
```

The error is:
`OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:`